# Getting gcc failed error while installing scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

When i am installing scrapy then i am getting the below error (**command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1**). I am using Centos, and yes i have the latest version of gcc installed. But i am not sure why i am getting this error. I tried googling it but could'nt find a solution

> OpenSSL/crypto/crypto.c: In function ‘initcrypto’:
>   OpenSSL/crypto/crypto.c:817: warning: implicit declaration of function
>   ‘ERR_load_crypto_strings’ OpenSSL/crypto/crypto.c:818: warning:
>   implicit declaration of function ‘OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms’
>   OpenSSL/crypto/crypto.c:832: error: ‘crypto_X509_New’ undeclared
>   (first use in this function) OpenSSL/crypto/crypto.c:833: error:
>   ‘crypto_X509Name_New’ undeclared (first use in this function)
>   OpenSSL/crypto/crypto.c:834: error: ‘crypto_X509Req_New’ undeclared
>   (first use in this function) OpenSSL/crypto/crypto.c:835: error:
>   ‘crypto_X509Store_New’ undeclared (first use in this function)
>   OpenSSL/crypto/crypto.c:836: error: ‘crypto_PKey_New’ undeclared
>   (first use in this function) OpenSSL/crypto/crypto.c:838: error:
>   ‘crypto_PKCS7_New’ undeclared (first use in this function)
>   OpenSSL/crypto/crypto.c:839: error: ‘crypto_NetscapeSPKI_New’
>   undeclared (first use in this function) OpenSSL/crypto/crypto.c:859:
>   error: ‘X509_FILETYPE_PEM’ undeclared (first use in this function)
>   OpenSSL/crypto/crypto.c:860: error: ‘X509_FILETYPE_ASN1’ undeclared
>   (first use in this function) OpenSSL/crypto/crypto.c:863: error:
>   ‘EVP_PKEY_RSA’ undeclared (first use in this function)
>   OpenSSL/crypto/crypto.c:864: error: ‘EVP_PKEY_DSA’ undeclared (first
>   use in this function) error: Setup script exited with error: command
>   'gcc' failed with exit status 1

I am also getting the same error when i am installing lxml

> src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:162737: error: ‘XML_XPATH_UNKNOWN_FUNC_ERROR’
>   undeclared (first use in this function) src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:162747:
>   error: ‘XML_XPATH_INVALID_OPERAND’ undeclared (first use in this
>   function) src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:162757: error:
>   ‘XML_XPATH_INVALID_TYPE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
>   src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:162767: error: ‘XML_XPATH_INVALID_ARITY’
>   undeclared (first use in this function) src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:162777:
>   error: ‘XML_XPATH_INVALID_CTXT_SIZE’ undeclared (first use in this
>   function) src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:162787: error:
>   ‘XML_XPATH_INVALID_CTXT_POSITION’ undeclared (first use in this
>   function) src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:163133: error: ‘LIBXSLT_VERSION’
>   undeclared (first use in this function) src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:163145:
>   error: ‘xsltLibxsltVersion’ undeclared (first use in this function)
>   src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:163157: error:
>   ‘__pyx_v_4lxml_5etree_XSLT_DOC_DEFAULT_LOADER’ undeclared (first use
>   in this function) src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:163157: error:
>   ‘xsltDocDefaultLoader’ undeclared (first use in this function)
>   src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:163166: error:
>   ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree__xslt_doc_loader’ undeclared (first use in this
>   function) error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed
>   with exit status 1

Comment: r u installing it with `easy_install` ??

Comment: Too localized and not constructive.

Answer (score 14):

You don't have the required C library to compile this module.
For lxml, you have to install the following packages.

```
sudo yum install python-devel libxml2-devel libxslt-devel
```

To resolve OpenSSL problem with Scrapy, install `pyOpenSSL`

```
sudo yum install pyOpenSSL
```

Note: These are the package names for fedora linux. Other distributions may have different package names.

Comment: on debian: `sudo apt-get install python-dev libxml2-dev libxslt-dev`

Answer (score 2):

Also make sure you have gcc installed:

```
sudo yum install gcc
```

Answer (score 1):

This was the solution for me on Linux Mint Nadia:

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev
```

I already had python-dev installed. I noticed that pip was able to install pyOpenSSL for me once the xml and xslt dependencies were installed.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev`

Answer (score 0):

my raspi automatically corrected to

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev
```

I also ran:

```
sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
```

not sure if it was neccessary.

Answer (score 0):

On Fedora 23, I had to install the following packages for `$ pip install scrapy` to complete successfully.

```
sudo dnf install python-devel libxml2-devel libxslt-devel libffi-devel libffi-devel
```

If the setup process complains about a missing file, for example:

```
fatal error: openssl/opensslv.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Do `$ dnf provides *filename` *(dnf provides *openssl/opensslv.h)* to find the required package and install it.

Answer (score 0):

#### Updated answer oktober 2019 - macOS

For people who are on `macOS` and to be more specific, im running `macOS Mojave v10.14.6` atm. I ran the following in my *terminal* and it helped my problem. Apparently my `Xcode Command-line` tools needed to be updated.

```
xcode-select --install
```